# Dark theme in Linux Mint makes texts in text boxes unreadable

Tags: linux-mint, theme

The dark default theme in Linux Mint is pretty great but there is an issue: all the text boxes get a black shade which makes the text entered difficult to read as the font colour of the text remains black. Is there any way to customise the theme/a workaround which solves this issue?

Comment: Is using another theme an option?

Comment: @xhienne there aren't any other dark themes. (In the themes settings, 'controls' section is what changes the major colour of the windows. In the controls section, there is only one dark theme: Mint-Y-dark.)